# compiling go with static c libraries

Tags: go

I'm trying to compile Go where it includes all the libraries that I need to run it. I'm trying to run the go binary in lambda so I need to add some C libraries (I think) when I build it (on linux), but when I do, I get this error:

```
[ec2-user@ip- src]$ go build -tags static --ldflags '-extldflags "-static -lpthread -lxml2 -lz -lm -llzma -lc"' main.go
# command-line-arguments
/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link: running gcc failed: exit status 1
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lm
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthread
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lrt
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthread
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthread
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lxml2
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lm
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llzma
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

---EDIT00000

I did a quick `ldconfig` search? and see this for example...are these the ones I need?

```
ldconfig -p | grep -e xml2 -e pthread -e lzma -e dl 
    libxml2.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libxml2.so.2
    libreadline.so.6 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libreadline.so.6
    libpthread.so.0 (libc6,x86-64, OS ABI: Linux 2.6.32) => /lib64/libpthread.so.0
    liblzma.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/liblzma.so.5
    libhandle.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libhandle.so.1
    libgpgme-pthread.so.11 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libgpgme-pthread.so.11
    libdl.so.2 (libc6,x86-64, OS ABI: Linux 2.6.32) => /lib64/libdl.so.2
    libdl.so (libc6,x86-64, OS ABI: Linux 2.6.32) => /lib64/libdl.so
```

Comment: Do you have the static libraries installed?

Comment: I believe so? code works on the ec2, but I'm not too familiar with C and go and how to check that

Comment: I don't understand -- the output here shows it's running on ec2, but you say it works on ec2. Where doesn't it work? You also are not supposed to statically link glibc, so I'm confused what actual goal is here.

Comment: ah so I'm compiling this on ec2 and then running it in aws lambda. Essentially I'm trying to get the kafka go confluent client to run in aws lambda. The confluent go client uses librdkafka which uses some other C libraries I think

Comment: You need to start by installing the static libraries on your ec2 instance. You should also check what cgo flags may be set in the confluent source. You may have better luck only statically linking the librdkafka specific dependencies and avoid glibc versions differing at runtime. If that fails, statically linking with a different libc like musl may have better results.

Comment: so when I do the `make` and `make install` on librdkafka, make sure to statically link its dependencies?